# Highly customizable CMS for existing NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, content-management-system

I have an existing  Nextjs and React Application with MongoDB Backend...Client wants to edit website, no code. How do i integrate a CMS?It's a corporate site...client wants to be able to manipulate everything,,,Navbar, content etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/) and I've worked with it.

[How to configure sanity with next js](https://www.sanity.io/blog/build-your-own-blog-with-sanity-and-next-js)

Comment: Can it help with an already existing website? and mongoDB backend?

Comment: yes. I've used it in a next.js app and after configuring it the client can make changes as it's needed.

Comment: jamal, how exactly do i do that? the documentation doesn't explain integration with existing project

Comment: You need create some schemas for your data and from there you can specify your data structure

Comment: i ended up using strapi :) but same work-around thanks